# spl_autoload_register() performance issues?

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

I guess there's something i'm missing about the pros of `spl_autoload_register()` over `autoload()` . 
From what i read, the advantage of `spl_autoload_register()` is that it can be registered multiple times, and then when i instantiate a class it will run trough all the registered autoload functions and load the correct one, which will give me more flexibility and allow me to use different functions for loading classes OR libraries.

But how is this considered a best practice to run over multiple registered functions over a single one?

(Or maybe i just didn't understand it at all)

Comment: It's considered better because it allows you to work with libraries that register their own autoloader... if you use libraries that have autoloaders, and don't use spl_autoload_register, then you have to rewrite all those library autoloaders to reflect your own single autoloader logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have said here: `spl_autoload_register` allows you to implement multiple autoloaders at the same time, which makes working with dependencies a whole lot easier.
Some other benefits are:

- Control: You can organize the autload stack: if you want your autoloader to be the first that is invoked, then you can call `spl_autoload_register`, passing `true` as the third argument, which prepends the autoloader
- Behaviour: You can register an autoloader, in such a way that, if it fails to register the autoloader for whatever reason, an exception is thrown. That makes life easier when debugging.
- Dynamic autoloaderS: you can register, but also [unregister](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-unregister.php) autoloaders, or just check which autoloaders are registered by [calling this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-functions.php).

In short: `spl_autload_register` isn't a singular function, it's part of an autloading system, that includes `spl_autload_functions` (to see which autoloaders are registered) and `spl_autoload_unregister` to remove any autoloaders you don't need anymore.
You can, if you so wish, also re-organize the autoloader stack by unregistering and append/prepend the autoloaders in such a way as to best suite your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it will be *slower* if you have several registered autoloaders. However, it better fits modern software development realities, in which many libraries from many different vendors are often included together in the same project. You can only define *one* `__autoload` function at a time which can act as an autoloader. However, each package individually can append an autoloader to the `spl_autoload` chain, without overwriting autoloaders registered by other packages. That's the entire point; it makes the use of autoloaders more flexible without everyone needing to worry about stepping on somebody else's foot.